# SQL Server stored procedure expects parameter

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

Why do I keep getting this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Procedure or function 'getTicket' expects parameter '@project_id', which was not supplied.'

I have created the procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getTicket]
    @project_id INT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        ticket_id, 
        ticket_name, 
        ticket_description, 
        ticket_url, 
        ticket_date_posted, 
        ticket_status 
    FROM 
        ticket 
    WHERE 
        project_id = @project_id
END
```

This is my vb code:

```
Dim sqlCom As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand
sqlCom.Connection = SQLcon
sqlCom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
sqlCom.CommandText = "getTicket"

sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@project_id", Request.QueryString("id"))

SQLcon.Open()

Dim DS As New DataSet
Dim SQLDA As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlCom.CommandText, SQLcon)
SQLDA.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 120

SQLDA.Fill(DS, "gvTable")
GridView1.DataSource = DS
GridView1.DataBind()

SQLcon.Close()
```

Comment: in this `sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@project_id", Request.QueryString("id"))` what is the data type of Request.QueryString("id")??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong:

```vb
Dim SQLDA As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlCom.CommandText, SQLcon)
```

It should be this:

```vb
Dim SQLDA As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlCom)
```

The problem is that you are creating a `SqlCommand` object and adding the parameter to it, but then you create a `SqlDataAdapter` that doesn't use that command.  Instead, you pass just the SQL code to the constructor as a `String` and so the data adapter creates a new `SqlCommand` object using that. Of course, that new command doesn't have the parameter added.

There are other aspects of your code that are suboptimal too.  Here are what I would consider the two sensible options:

```vb
Dim sqlCom As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("getTicket", SQLcon) 
    With {.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure, .CommandTimeout = 120}
sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@project_id", Request.QueryString("id"))

Dim SQLDA As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlCom)
```

and...

```vb
Dim SQLDA As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("getTicket", SQLcon)
With SQLDA.SelectCommand
    .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    .CommandTimeout = 120
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@project_id", Request.QueryString("id"))
End With
```

Even then, that's ignoring the fact that `AddWithValue` should be avoided and `Add` used with an explicit setting of the `Value` property, e.g.

```vb
.Parameters.Add("@project_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Request.QueryString("id"))
```

Comment: that't it.. you solved it

changed this <br/>

Dim SQLDA As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlCom.CommandText, SQLcon)<br/>

to this<br/>

Dim SQLDA As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlCom)

Answer (score 0):

Many ways two pass parameters.

```
sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@project_id", SqlDbType.Int,Convert.toInt32(Request.QueryString("id")))

OR

sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@project_id", SqlDbType.Int);
sqlCom.Parameters("@project_id").Value = Convert.toInt32(Request.QueryString("id"));
```